# How to shorten string to specific length according to textBox1.Length c#

Tags: c#, string, winforms, string-length

I need to know how to shorten a string to a certain length, I tried `string.Trim()` but it is not working. Sorry I'm still a beginner.

Thanks

**Edit**

I'm trying to cut off padding from decrypted text.
For example: A user inputs text, the user encrypts and decrypts text. On the decrypted text there is padding left...

**Edit 2**

I'm using `PaddingMode.PKCS7`

Comment: A lot of `string` methods might help you. Can you please show your string first and the result string as you want?

Comment: @DilanV Perhaps the problem is in the encryption/decryption instead of being in the padding :)

Comment: @DilanV Compare your code with http://stackoverflow.com/a/4925859/613130

Comment: @DilanV Perhaps you are setting the PaddingMode only on encryptor only on decrypt, or you have different PaddingMode. The PaddingMode, if present, must be the same on both encrypt and decrypt.

Comment: @DilanV No, it's you that should post your code.

Comment: @xanatos don't worry your answer worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the problem is probably in the encryption/decryption. You are encrypting/decrypting with `PaddingMode.Zeros`, that pads with `\0`... Now, you could

```
string decrypted = ...
decrypted = decrypted.TrimEnd('\0');
```

but it would be at least partially wrong.

Change both the encryption and the decryption adding:

```
algo.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126
```

(where `algo` is the object you use to encrypt/decrypt, like a `RijndaelManaged`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Substring()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of string class like

```
textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 7);
```

Answer (score -1):

Strings are immutable, that means you cannot modify them. You have to re-assign the return value of the string methods to the string variable. You can use `String.Substring`:

```
int length = textBox1.Text.Length;
longString = longString.Substring(0, Math.Min(length, longString.Length));
```